# How can I use 2 decimals using money in ASP.NET web forms?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I know, there are a few answers here, but neither of them works.

So here is the scenario:

Got a GridView and in one of these columns, a price is declared. In the SQL Database, I use `money` to declare the price. The GridView will import the data from the database programmatically
 Code here:

```
        var con = new SqlConnection();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\hugow\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OSGS_v2\dataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        string cmdText = null;
        string usrName = Request.Cookies["usrData"]["usrName"];
        cmdText = "SELECT orderID, Products, orderPrice, date FROM orderData WHERE orderUser=@usr";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@usr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usrName;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        stdT.DataSource = dt;
        stdT.DataBind();
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
```

And I want to show the price as a two decimal price (0,00). The problem is: It shows 4 decimals (0,0000).

2 Questions:

1. How to show 2 decimals instead of 4?
2. Why does `money` have 4 decimals instead of 2?

I use Web Forms, not MVC.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `<ItemTemplate>` you can use this:

```
<%# string.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("orderPrice"))) %>
```

With BoundField you use `DataFormatString`:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="orderPrice" HeaderText="Price" DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
```

`0:c` will give you the correct currency format with the corresponding money symbol for your current localization. If you want a numeric value with 2 decimals you would use `0:N2`.

For all format options see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That works but is also my problem: I import all the data via code, is it possible to do that in code behind? Because in this situation I have to remove all my .cs code.

Comment: You don't have to remove all your cs code. You would only have to edit 1 line in your aspx file. You could also use this in your query, then you don't need to change anything else `CAST(orderPrice AS numeric(8, 2)) AS orderPrice`

Answer (score 1):

Just tell your system to wrap the value to two decimals,

```
decimal.Round("your value", 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: Cannot be executed

Comment: What value are you trying to wrap? usrName?

Comment: If you are trying to wrap a string, you can run; String.Format("{0:.##}", "your string")

Comment: Correction orderPrice

Comment: Just refractor the price value in a separate integer and format it